# Question about code for tables

Tags: tables

I have been trying to understand why my code won't produce a table:

```
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Exercise \arabic*:]
  \item 5 + 7 = 12
  \item 9 + 1 = 10
  \item 2 * 2 = 4
  \end{enumerate}
```

I have tried using the $ sign, but unfortunately I have no idea why I'm not getting a table. What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you elaborate some more. What do you mean by not getting a table? If you want a `table`, use `tabular`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: I think you are on the lookout for the `align` environment from package `amsmath`. Having said that, please read some basic introductory material.

Comment: Ok, so my code there is lacking? I thought if I just added the $ symbols the table would appear? 

Specifically, how do I add table or tabular?

Answer (score 3):

Well, that code is not suitable for a table is for a list. You need to use something more adequate for that:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\section{Exercise} 

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.3em}  % default value: 5pt
$\begin{array}{r@{\qquad}rcrcr}  % more spacing between first two columns
1. & 5 & + & 7 & = & 12 \\
2. & 9 & - & 1 & = & 8 \\
3. & 2 & * & 6 & = & 12 \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

It is not, of course, the best solution. However I illustrate because it is more or less the idea you have or how about trying to work maths out the right environment.

However, when you work within the math environment, you can use the `amsmath` package and any of its settings, such as `align` (as such recommends Johannes_B) that allows you to align mathematical expressions without using a table (although internally, the `LaTeX` logic to aligning them is the same).

[image: Result of the first suggestion]

---

### Addenda

OK, the preceding solution isn't perfect. The most important reason is because **is not the way** for typing math in `LaTeX`. A better idea is to use `amsmath`, and we will get something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises} 

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    \text{\textbf{i}} \quad   & 5 + 7 & = 12 \\
    \text{\textbf{ii}} \quad  & 9 + 1 & = 10 \\
    \text{\textbf{iii}} \quad & 2 * 2 & = \phantom{0}4
\end{alignat*}    
\end{document}
```

As you can see, this environment works in mathematical environment even if you don't use `$` symbols.

[image: Solution with amsmath]

Comment: I know, in fact I prefer to use `align` instead of a table or `array`. This is a very, very simple and awful way to do it. But is simple. @Mico you are the specialist in tables, you should improve this answer and show a more elegant solution with the suggestions you made ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting some thing like this?  If not, please explain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Exercise \arabic*:]
  \item 5 + 7 = 12
  \item 9 + 1 = 10
  \item 2 * 2 = 4
  \end{enumerate}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries Exercise \stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}l >{$}c<{$}!{$=$}r}
    & 5 + 7 & 12 \\
    & 9 + 1 & 10 \\
    & 2 * 2 & 4 \\
    & 2 \times 2 & 4
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, here is the `array` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  $\begin{array}{@{}>{\text{\bfseries Exercise  \stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}}l c!{=}r}
    & 5 + 7 & 12 \\
    & 9 + 1 & 10 \\
    & 2 * 2 & 4 \\
    & 2 \times 2 & 4
  \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. 

What am I doing wrong, or what code am I missing?

Comment: @Ishihara Well, you didn't give the full code (like I did). Hence, I can only guess. Did you load `enumitem`?

Comment: Well I copied and pasted your code into the Mathematics section of Stackexchange (where I was going to post my question) and the table didn't appear when I added the $ symbols.

Comment: @Ishihara You need to understand the code first instead of paste it. It means you need to understand `LaTeX` to know what you do.

Comment: @Ishihara math.stackexchange uses mathjax.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess it uses array then?

Comment: @Ishihara So, you want to type this in math.stackexchange?. Then you may use `array`. But why don't you ask this there itself?

Comment: @Ishihara the point is that mathjax does not use tex (so questions about it are off topic for this site) and in particular you can't assume that latex packages such as `enumitem` whose syntax you were using are emulated by mathjax.